# Appium Detect Alertdialog

Tags: appium

I'm writing a UI test script in Python, after performing a click, there might be an alert window popping up. If so, I need to press a button on that window. I wonder if there's a way to detect alert dialogs in Appium API? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: please share that dialog box with locators for that page. Then only i can say anything

Comment: @Gaurav I just added a screen shot. Let me know if that's the one you want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems like there is no locator available for Yes and NO button. Can you try to use UIAutomator to find the locators for this dialog box?

Comment: @Gaurav Yes, I can find them. I just didn't show them in the image.

Comment: great!! now you can perform any action by using those locators.

Answer (score 2):

simple and best way is doing through capabilities

```
capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts",true);
```

This will only accept alerts from your App and not the system Alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Place your pointer on Yes, No button, you will get ID's of those if they have separate ID's. Then use

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('id of the button').click()
```

If they do not have ID then use

```
self.driver.find_element_by_name('OK').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit unrelated to the question, but I hope this will give you a clue.

You can use the XPATH to locate the element. well, this approach is not really recommended. But this could be useful if the element is doesn't have any ID, accessibility name, name, or label. where the information is only class, and value.

for example you could do something like this:
`//android.widget.Button[contains(@text,'OK')]`

I am not sure about the class name for Alert dialog on android. But this is my approach when facing some problem on iOS automation, for example my app have custom alert with 3 button (all of them is customized), button Open, Close, and Report:

```
//UIAAlert[*]//UIAButton[@name='Report']
```

You could do same approach to locate any element which is unable to locate by normal approach.